# Complex Integration: $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x^2 +1)} dx $

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm supposed to evaluate:

$$  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x^2 +1)} dx $$

**Attempt**

Consider $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{iz}}{x(k^2x^2 +1)} dz $

Simple poles at $z = \pm \frac{i}{k} $, simple pole at z = 0.

Consider contour the following contour:

[image]

Residue at $z=\frac{i}{k}$ is $-\frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{k}} $

Residue at $z=0$ is $0$.

By Jordan's lemma, the integral along the chord disappears as the circle blows up. Thus only integral along real axis remains.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{x(k^2x^2+1)} = 2\pi i \times (-\frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{k}}) $$

Looks good, as due to parity the cosine part disappears.

Thus, $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x(k^2x^2 +1)} dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{k}} $

Comment: The residue at $0$ is _not_ $0$. It's a simple pole, so the residue cannot be $0$. The residue is $1$.

Comment: But if you take limit of z=0 at $\frac{sin z}{k^2z^2 + 1}$ you get 0.

Comment: But in the integral, you don't have $\sin z$, you have $e^{iz}$.

Comment: Ok so the integral is actually $\pi \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{1}{k}}\right)$. This looks right when I use wolframalpha for k = 1.

Comment: @user44840:  Would you like to post an answer to your question (with all patches applied)?